# Hidden Android Apps

Tags: android

Is it possible to have one app icon with a home screen that provides access to multiple apps (without icons) developed and deployed independently, or does that contradict the android app paradigm altogether?

My product managers basically want me to copy a web app that has multiple sub-features which we deploy separately, each with its own api, and do it in android. What i think i'm learning is Android can be organized with modules in the solution but is not built to be deployed separately, and breaking the web app down into multiple independent android apps that don't have icons but are called by another app is not usual for some reason.

Comment: so service will do to implement these multiple apps?

Comment: it would be a single screen app that would serve as a home page from which the other apps would be launched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that puts an icon on the home screen is the LAUNCHER category intent in the Manifest. You can always start other apps on the phone given you know their package names.

That being said, if the apps are developed and deployed independently, then it does seem against some paradigm to require the end users to install multiple apps just to get the full functionality of what you are independently developing.

Comment: If I removed the icon, would the user be able to uninstall the app easily?

Comment: Not easily, no. They'd have to go into the settings window and uninstall. Matter of fact, I'm not even sure the Play store allows apps without launcher activities...

Comment: well, i built a deployment system to deploy and update our android apps in house using Jenkins.... but my concern is if the user had to uninstall and reinstall an app because of an issue on their phone, they wouldn't be able to easily, which you answered. thank you:)